# "Thanks for installing Anaconda!" pop-up every single time I start Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

Every time I start Anaconda, I get this pop-up. I tried both buttons, I tried checking/unchecking the checkbox, but it always comes back.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a privileges problem. Did you install with elevated privileges, but are running without?

Answer (score 0):

As @merv mentioned, this problem is related to user privileges.
On Linux, start the application with the root user, on Windows with the administrator user.

It worked for me on both Ubuntu and Windows 10, I hope it helps!